# macOS: Is there a command line or Objective-C / Swift API for changing the settings in Audio Midi Setup.app?

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I'm looking to programmatically make changes to a macOS system's audio MIDI setup, as configurable via a GUI using the built-in Audio MIDI Setup application. Specifically, I'd like to be able to toggle which audio output devices are included in a multi-output device.

Is there any method available for accomplishing that? I'll accept a command line solution, a compiled solution using something like Objective-C or Swift, or whatever else; as long as I can trigger it programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is.

On Mac there is this framework called Core Audio. The interface found in AudioHardware.h is an interface to the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer). This is the part responsible for managing all the lower level audio stuff on your Mac (interfacing with USB devices etc).

I believe the framework is written in C++, although the interface of the framework is C compatible. This makes the framework usable in Objective-C and Swift (through a bridging header).

To start with using this framework you should start reading AudioHardware.h in CoreAudio.framework. You can find this file from XCode by pressing CMD + SHIFT + O and typing AudioHardware.h.

To give you an example as starter (which creates a new aggregate with no subdevices):

```
// Create a CFDictionary to hold all the options associated with the to-be-created aggregate
CFMutableDictionaryRef params = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 10, NULL, NULL);

// Define the UID of the to-be-created aggregate
CFDictionaryAddValue(params, CFSTR(kAudioAggregateDeviceUIDKey), CFSTR("DemoAggregateUID"));
// Define the name of the to-be-created aggregate
CFDictionaryAddValue(params, CFSTR(kAudioAggregateDeviceNameKey), CFSTR("DemoAggregateName"));

// Define if the aggregate should be a stacked aggregate (ie multi-output device)
static char stacked = 0; // 0 = stacked, 1 = aggregate
CFNumberRef cf_stacked = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberCharType, &stacked);
CFDictionaryAddValue(params, CFSTR(kAudioAggregateDeviceIsStackedKey), cf_stacked);

// Create the actual aggrgate device
AudioObjectID resulting_id = 0;
OSStatus result = AudioHardwareCreateAggregateDevice(params, &resulting_id);

// Check if we got an error.
// Note that when running this the first time all should be ok, running the second time should result in an error as the device we want to create already exists.
if (result)
{
    printf("Error: %d\n", result);
}
```

There are some frameworks which make interfacing a bit easier by wrapping Core Audio call. *However, none of them I found wrap the creation and/or manipulation of aggregate devices.* Still, they can be usefull to find the right devices in the system: [AMCoreAudio](https://github.com/rnine/AMCoreAudio) (Swift), [JACK](https://github.com/jackaudio) (C & C++), [libsoundio](https://github.com/andrewrk/libsoundio) (C), [RtAudio](https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio) (C++).

Comment: "// 0 = stacked, 1 = aggregate" -- Looks like it's the other way around